# Stop HTML Video Autoplay on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, video, mobile, autoplay

On the desktop version of my website, a video autoplays in the background. I'd like the video to not autoplay on a mobile device (i.e. if screen width < 800) so that the video doesn't download. For some reason, I can't get this particular video to cease to autoplay with javascript. Here's the relevant text:

```html
<video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://fiercefreedom.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/FierceCropped.mp4">
    </video>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  if (screenWidth < 800){
  $('#background-video').removeAttr('autoplay');
  } else {
   $('background-video').attr('autoplay');
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI `$('background-video').attr('autoplay');` is missing the `#` character.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready` only begins AFTER the page is loaded, thus the browser has already began the autoplay.

Instead, you should remove the `autoplay` attribute from the static HTML, and only add it then if the width is greater than 800.

---

```
<video id="background-video" loop muted>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://fiercefreedom.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/FierceCropped.mp4">
</video>

$(function() {
  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  if (screenWidth >= 800) {
    $('#background-video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
  }
});
```

Comment: That does stop the autoplay on mobile browsers, but the video also doesn't autoplay on a desktop browser (i.e. larger window) with this solution. Here's what I have (I switched the screenWidth requirement to see if it would autoplay on a screen < 800): https://jsfiddle.net/v6d41t35/

Comment: @NolanBauer Review this line in your fiddle `screenWidth < 800` ... I have used `screenWidth >= 800` above.

Comment: Made a revision: https://jsfiddle.net/v6d41t35/1/. I still don't see the video autoplaying. Any ideas?

Comment: Add the jQuery library to the JSFiddle, you are missing it.

Comment: Also make sure the HTML window of the JSFiddle itself is 800 wide when running it. It doesn't check your monitor width.

Comment: Second Revision: https://jsfiddle.net/v6d41t35/2/. Thanks for your help. I added the jQuery library and the window should load larger than 800. I still don't see an autoplay though.